# Bash: why can't put redirecting before grouped commands using curly brace

Tags: bash, shell

following shell command execute failed:

```
$ >/dev/null { : ; }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

but if put redirecting before simple command is ok:

```
$ >/dev/null :
```

This is not mentioned in bash manual.

Comment: How can I do this, because this shell is put into make recipe, like this: `$(Q) { xxx ; }`. Q will expand to `>/dev/null` to hide all compile log

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why can't put redirecting before grouped commands using curly brace

Because the language grammar disallows it.

From [posix shell manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) in `2.4 Reserved words` can be read the following emphasis mine:

> The following words shall be recognized as reserved words:
>
> ! do esac in
> { done fi then
> } elif for until
> case else if while
>
> This recognition shall only occur when none of the characters is quoted and when the word is used as:
>
> - **The first word of a command**
> - The first word following one of the reserved words other than case, for, or in
> - The third word in a case command (only in is valid in this case)
> - The third word in a for command (only in and do are valid in this case)

For `{` to introduce a command grouping it has to be the first word in a command. The same counts for example for `</dev/null if false; them echo 1; fi` or `</dev/null while true; do echo 1; done`. The reserved word has to be the first word in the command.

> How can I do this

You put it after the braces or the command. It will "apply" the redirection for all the commands "inside" the grouping.

```
{ echo 1; } >/dev/null
while echo this will go to file1; do echo this too; break; done >/tmp/file1.txt
if read a; then read b; echo yes; else echo no; fi </tmp/file1 >/tmp/file2
```

> like this: $(Q) { xxx ; }

Doing it like this is not possible, because the redirection is parsed before command substitution `$(...)` is expanded. You can't script it like this. You could use eval re reevaluate your expression, but [eval is one letter from evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). The proper way for you are searching for is most probably to redirect stdout or a custom file descriptor to the destination file using `exec` like `exec 1>/dev/null` or like `exec {FD}>/dev/null; { cmd; } >${FD}`.